# Смена изображения при нажатии

Tags: html, javascript

Необходимо реализовать следующую возможность:
при нажатии на иконку цвета - должно смениться основное изображение.
[Пример](http://www.sirius-potolki.ru/) (внизу, под калькулятором). Буду благодарен, если кто подскажет, как это сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На иконку цвета вешаешь `onclick="color('цвет')"`
Изображение должно иметь id, например `id="big"`

JS:

```
function color(c){
 switch(c){
  case 'red': document.getElementById("big").src = 'Ссылка на красное изображение'; break;
  case 'green': document.getElementById("big").src = 'Ссылка на зеленое изображение'; break;
 }
}
```

и т.д.

Comment: как вариант, можно избежать switch, на случай если цветов много, и использовать наименование цвета в имени файла большой картинки.

    function color(c){
        document.getElementById("big").src = 'img/big_img_' + c + '.jpg';
    }

Comment: Что неправильно?
<script type="text/javascript">  
function color(c){  
 switch(c){  
  'red': document.getElementById("color-box").src = '/images/color-box/l03.jpg'; break;  
 }  
}  
</script>  
<img src="/images/color-box/azalee_33.png" onclick="color('red')";>  
<div>  
<img id="color-box">  
</div>

Comment: перед 'red' напиши case 

case 'red': .....

Я все время забываю про это

Comment: Все, теперь работает! Благодарю. Очень помогли